# Binary objects Hu moments - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to calculate binary objects Hu moments based on the code from [R. C. Gonzalez, R. E. Woods, & S. L. Eddins book Digital Image Processing Using MATLAB](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/dipum/invmoments.m) using the code below but I get all zeros. Why and how can I fix it?

```
I =   rgb2gray(imread('pillsetc.png'));
bw = imbinarize(I);
bw = imfill(bw,'holes');
bw = bwareaopen(bw, 100);
imshow(bw)
hold on;
[B,L] = bwboundaries(bw,'noholes');
stats = regionprops(L,'Centroid');


for i = 1 : numel(stats)
    b = B{i};
    c = stats(i).Centroid;
    y = b(:,1);
    x = b(:,2);
    plot( b(:,2),b(:,1),'Color','red','linewidth',1);
    text(c(1),c(2),num2str(i),'Color','red'); 
    invmoments(i)
end
```

Comment: It appears that `invmoments` takes an image as input, not an integer.

Comment: Get the `'Image'` output of `regionprops`, and pass that to `invmoments`.