# Object ellipticity based on the moment invariants - Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

Following a question about [Hu moments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62243841/binary-objects-hu-moments-matlab) and a question regarding [object Ellipse Variance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62236581/understand-and-calculate-object-ellipse-variance-using-matlab) I used the code from this [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dipum/dipum-toolbox/master/dipum/invmoments.m)  to try to calculate ellipticity based on the moment invariants like in the image below (Based on [A Beginner’s Guide to Image Shape Feature Extraction Techniques](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/9780429287794)).
I the code I used (only checking the first 2 objects) I do not get a value close to 1 (which should indicate an Ellipticity) when I have an ellipse object. Can someone please explain what I did wrong?

[image]

code:

```
clc;
clear;
close all;

% Image processing
I= rgb2gray(imread('https://az877327.vo.msecnd.net/~/media/images/products/2005/other/mipix%20ellipses%20full%20frame.jpg?v=1&h=550&w=800&crop=1'));
bw = imbinarize(I);
bw = imfill(bw,'holes');
bw = bwareaopen(bw, 100);
imshow(bw)
hold on;
[B,L] = bwboundaries(bw,'noholes');
stats = regionprops(L,'Centroid','Image');

%Loop - data acquisition
for i = 1 : 2 %numel(stats)
    b = B{i};
    c = stats(i).Centroid;
    f = stats(i).Image;
    y = b(:,1);
    x = b(:,2);
    plot( b(:,2),b(:,1),'Color','red','linewidth',1);
    text(c(1),c(2),num2str(i),'Color','red'); 

    %based on https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dipum/dipum-toolbox/master/dipum/invmoments.m
    [M,N] = size(f);
    [x,y] = meshgrid(1:N,1:M);

    % Turn x,y, and F into column vectors to make the summations a bit
    % easier to compute in the following.
    x = x(:);
    y = y(:);
    f = f(:);

    % DIPUM3E equation (13-27)
    m.m00 = sum(f);
    % Protect against divide-by-zero warnings.
    if (m.m00 == 0)
       m.m00 = eps;
    end
    % The other central moments:  
    m.m10 = sum(x .* f);
    m.m01 = sum(y .* f);
    m.m11 = sum(x .* y .* f);
    m.m20 = sum(x.^2 .* f);
    m.m02 = sum(y.^2 .* f);
    m.m30 = sum(x.^3 .* f);
    m.m03 = sum(y.^3 .* f);
    m.m12 = sum(x .* y.^2 .* f);
    m.m21 = sum(x.^2 .* y .* f);

    % DIPUM3E equations (13-28) through (13-30).
    xbar = m.m10 / m.m00;
    ybar = m.m01 / m.m00;

    e.eta11 = (m.m11 - ybar*m.m10) / m.m00^2;
    e.eta20 = (m.m20 - xbar*m.m10) / m.m00^2;
    e.eta02 = (m.m02 - ybar*m.m01) / m.m00^2;
    e.eta30 = (m.m30 - 3 * xbar * m.m20 + 2 * xbar^2 * m.m10) / ...
                m.m00^2.5;
    e.eta03 = (m.m03 - 3 * ybar * m.m02 + 2 * ybar^2 * m.m01) / ...
                m.m00^2.5;
    e.eta21 = (m.m21 - 2 * xbar * m.m11 - ybar * m.m20 + ...
               2 * xbar^2 * m.m01) / m.m00^2.5;
    e.eta12 = (m.m12 - 2 * ybar * m.m11 - xbar * m.m02 + ...
               2 * ybar^2 * m.m10) / m.m00^2.5;

    % DIPUM3E Table 13.8.
    phi(1) = e.eta20 + e.eta02;
    phi(2) = (e.eta20 - e.eta02)^2 + 4*e.eta11^2;
    phi(3) = (e.eta30 - 3*e.eta12)^2 + (3*e.eta21 - e.eta03)^2;
    phi(4) = (e.eta30 + e.eta12)^2 + (e.eta21 + e.eta03)^2;
    phi(5) = (e.eta30 - 3*e.eta12) * (e.eta30 + e.eta12) * ...
             ( (e.eta30 + e.eta12)^2 - 3*(e.eta21 + e.eta03)^2 ) + ...
             (3*e.eta21 - e.eta03) * (e.eta21 + e.eta03) * ...
             ( 3*(e.eta30 + e.eta12)^2 - (e.eta21 + e.eta03)^2 );
    phi(6) = (e.eta20 - e.eta02) * ( (e.eta30 + e.eta12)^2 - ...
                                     (e.eta21 + e.eta03)^2 ) + ...
             4 * e.eta11 * (e.eta30 + e.eta12) * (e.eta21 + e.eta03);
    phi(7) = (3*e.eta21 - e.eta03) * (e.eta30 + e.eta12) * ...
             ( (e.eta30 + e.eta12)^2 - 3*(e.eta21 + e.eta03)^2 ) + ...
             (3*e.eta12 - e.eta30) * (e.eta21 + e.eta03) * ...
             ( 3*(e.eta30 + e.eta12)^2 - (e.eta21 + e.eta03)^2 );


    disp('Object number:');
    disp(i);
    Is = (m.m20 * m.m02-m.m11^2)/m.m00^4;
    Em1= 16*pi^2*Is
    Em2= (16*pi^2*Is)^-1
    min(Em1, Em2)
end
```

Comment: `if (m.m00 == 0)` -> skip all following computations, since they'll be useless (you can use `continue`). Is this even possible, an object with zero pixels? Regarding your question: please remove the computation of `e.etaXX` and `phi`, which are not actually used and just complicate your question (see [mre]).

Comment: You seem to have implemented the equations correctly. If you get bad results, maybe the book has a bug? :) I don't understand why Hu moments are named, but not actually used.

Comment: Thinking about this a bit more, I actually don’t understand how you could possibly compare a shape to an ellipse through the second order moments. These moments can tell you which ellipse is most similar to the shape, but not how different the shape is from that ellipse.

Comment: Your comment says that you're computing the central moments, but you're not. All of the *m_x,x* in equation 3.19 are central moments. Change this and you'll get values almost exactly equal to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments, you need to use the central moments rather than raw moments as your code is doing. See [Measuring Shape: Ellipticity, Rectangularity, and Triangularity](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Paul_Rosin/publication/2549913_Measuring_Shape_Ellipticity_Rectangularity_and_Triangularity/links/0c96051ac5228d817e000000/Measuring-Shape-Ellipticity-Rectangularity-and-Triangularity.pdf)

Removing the unnecessary calculations for `eta` and `phi`, the last part of your code should be:

```
% Calculate Raw Moments:  
m.m10 = sum(x .* f);
m.m01 = sum(y .* f);
m.m11 = sum(x .* y .* f);
m.m20 = sum(x.^2 .* f);
m.m02 = sum(y.^2 .* f);
m.m30 = sum(x.^3 .* f);
m.m03 = sum(y.^3 .* f);
m.m12 = sum(x .* y.^2 .* f);
m.m21 = sum(x.^2 .* y .* f);

% DIPUM3E equations (13-28) through (13-30).
xbar = m.m10 / m.m00;
ybar = m.m01 / m.m00;

% Calculate Central Moments:
m.mu11 = m.m11 - xbar*m.m01;
m.mu20 = m.m20 - xbar*m.m10;
m.mu02 = m.m02 - ybar*m.m01;

disp('Object number:');
disp(i);

Is = (m.mu20 * m.mu02 - m.mu11^2)/m.m00^4;

Em1= 16*pi^2*Is
Em2= (16*pi^2*Is)^-1
min(Em1, Em2)
```

With these changes, the results for the first two objects are:

```
Object number:
 1
Em1 =  1.000005232603003
Em2 =    9.999947674243773e-01
ans =    9.999947674243773e-01
Object number:
 2
Em1 =    9.999818710527637e-01
Em2 =  1.000018129275901
ans =    9.999818710527637e-01
```

Comment: This is probably right, but does not match what is in the paper being followed by OP. It is likely that that paper is wrong, though. Also, I don’t see how this measures ellipticity, any non-elliptical shape will have the same values of the 2nd order central moments as some ellipse.  This is exactly how ellipses are typically fitted to a shape.

Comment: @CrisLuengo You're right, the authors do not seem to consider this a very robust method. "While all perfect circles will produce identical values of I1 other shapes can also produce the same value..." They are simply taking the value for the moment that a circle would give, and use the fact that any affine transformation of that circle (i.e. an ellipse) will give the same value. That doesn't rule out other shapes producing that value. And yes, it appears that the book the OP is using is being very sloppy.

Comment: @beaker Thanks for adding the `% Calculate Central Moments` section. I left the `m.m00 = sum(f);`. In summary, I understand that this is just a way to measure object fitting to ellipse but not a way to calculate Ellipse Variance (unfortunately).

Comment: @wrek This is the correct way to calculate the ellipticity as shown in your question. If this measure of ellipticity doesn't work for you, the paper I cited mentions 3 other methods.